# PyPDF2 doesn't display barcode (pdf417) after using update_page_form_field_values()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I'm trying to modify a pdf found here
https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-130.pdf

It has a barcode at the bottom that I need to keep. However if I use the update_page_form_field_values() function the pdf doesn't show the barcode. How do I prevent this?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader,PdfFileWriter


reader = PdfFileReader("i-130.pdf")
pager = reader.getPage(0)
field_dict = {
"Pt2Line4b_GivenName[0]": "Mark"
}

writer = PdfFileWriter()
writer.add_page(pager)
writer.update_page_form_field_values(pager,fields=field_dict)

with open("newfile.pdf", "wb") as fh:
    writer.write(fh)
```

I've tried modifying the basic fields by accessing the forms directly, but I have issues with all the forms showing up. Run this code snippet separately, but you can't update the GivenName field directly

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader,PdfFileWriter
from PyPDF2.generic import NameObject, IndirectObject, BooleanObject


reader = PdfFileReader("i-130.pdf")
pager = reader.getPage(0)

annot3 = pager['/Annots'][18].get_object()
annot3.update({NameObject("/V"):NameObject("Mark")})


writer = PdfFileWriter()
writer._root_object.update({NameObject("/AcroForm"):IndirectObject(len(writer._objects),0,writer)})
need_appearances = NameObject("/NeedAppearances")
writer._root_object["/AcroForm"][need_appearances] = BooleanObject(True)

with open("newfile.pdf", "wb") as fh:
    writer.write(fh)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't really give you any details on why this is so and what negative effects might result from approaching it this way, BUT...

The issue is driven by the `self.set_need_appearances_writer()` call at the top of the `update_page_form_field_values` function definition. To test, I commented that line out in my PyPDF2 distribution (see how-to below, but be advised, this is NOT a good long term solution), and the following code:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
rdr = PdfFileReader("i-130.pdf")
fields_dict = {
    "Pt2Line4b_GivenName[0]": "Mark"
}
wtr = PdfFileWriter()
wtr.append_pages_from_reader(rdr)
# wtr.set_need_appearances_writer()
wtr.update_page_form_field_values(wtr.pages[0], fields_dict)
with open("i-130-prefilled.pdf", "wb") as ofile:
    wtr.write(ofile)
```

produces output:

[image]

The bad news is that the resultant PDF is quite a bit smaller than the original (~150 KB smaller), so even if it looks like an identical copy with a few fields filled out, there's clearly something more that's lacking. One of those "things" is the font in which the field values are rendered. The original version rendered entered values in a fixed width font like courier new, but the modified version displays a standard "sans" font. Conversely, you can replace the `append_pages_from_reader` call with `clone_document_from_reader` in which case you'll end up with a prepopulated version that DOES preserve the font, but the file size is ~300 KB *larger than* the original.  No matter how you slice it, *something* is "not the same".

Bottom line:
I'm not sure I'd go with any solution without understanding what happens "under the hood" with that `set_need_appearances_writer` call. As such, I'd advise direct engagement with the good folks who picked up the baton and started actively working on the PyPDF2 library again earlier this year. You can find them at https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2.

As promised, here's how you can *test* the solution in your own environment (but please don't do this and call it a day ;)):

- navigate to the dist folder for your PyPDF2 install and open _writer.py (in VSCode, you can right click on the call to `update_page_form_field_values` and select 'Go to Definition')
- comment out the offending line as shown below:
  [image]

Comment: Hi Sam, Thank you for pointing out the issue so clearly  You've identified two issues: (1) `set_need_appearances_writer` causes problems (2) Some page resources such as fonts were not included. Sadly, [PyPDF2 has several issues with forms](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Aworkflow-forms). My suggestion for this one would be to add a parameter `set_need_appearances: bool=True`. Do you want to do it on GitHub via PR to get the attribution?

Comment: Regarding "something is not the same": It could be content compression. I haven't looked into that topic, but I think PyPDF2 de-compresses content streams, but it does not automatically re-compress.

Comment: Thanks @MartinThoma! Happy to submit a PR with that enhancement if not already done. I'll take a look in a bit and submit one if I don't see an equivalent. Good call on content compression as a possible culprit for the size increase. I know from past experience how convoluted that can get.